# How import java project (that contains two java project ) in IDE Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to import a java  project `MyProject1`that contains two java project ( `Myparser` and `Myproject3` ) in IDE Eclipse.

the folder that contains the three projects is as follows:

```
   .metadata  
    projet1
    projet2
    projet3
```

note that the folder   `.metadata`  contains `.plugins`

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an Eclipse workspace, and workspaces are not portable.

From inside Eclipse, you can use **File**->**Import**->**Existing projects into workspace** to import `projet1`, etc., into a new workspace.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.